# Edge crease not working with subdivision surface

Tags: mesh, subdivision-surface

I'm getting holes and rounded corners on a straight bumpout on the inner surface of a cylinder. I've creased all the sharp angles but something isn't working correctly.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I suppose you have subdivision modifier after edge split, reorder them.

Comment: If it is not, merge double vertices, M -> by distance

Comment: I'm guessing that's an STL you downloaded form somewhere, it's a mess! Check for edges that are very close to the edges you are having trouble with. Also, if you used `Select Sharp Edge`, a messy mesh like that might have selected edges you don't really want. Please attach your .blend file to your question and we can take a look at it for you, without that we would just be guessing... https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @Psyonic I did get it from someone else and it is definitely a mess. I used select sharp edges but had to go in and select some individually. I’ll play around with that.

Comment: @Crantisz I’ll try that but won’t it move the vertices? I need some precision there.

Comment: If they share same location - nope